# MUI multiple select not working after adding button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Wanted to add buttons below select dropdown menu with specific height , but when i try to put menu item inside div , multiple select stopped working , no idea why it's happening . Need Help !!!

CodeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-breeze-flkcjl?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1666

```
   import "./styles.css";
   import { useState } from "react";

   import {
   Select,
   Typography,
   MenuItem,
   Box, 
   SelectChangeEvent,
    Button
   } from "@mui/material";

   const displayedBlockOptions = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];

   export default function App() {
   const [val, setVal] = useState<string[]>([]);

   const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof val>) => {
   const {
   target: { value }
   } = event;
   setVal(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
   };
   return (
   <div className="App">
   <Select
    displayEmpty
    multiple
    // MenuProps={{
    //   sx: { height: "300px" }
    // }}
    value={val}
    onChange={handleChange}
    renderValue={(selected: any) => {
      if (selected.length === 0) {
        return (
          <Typography noWrap fontWeight={400} fontSize="13px">
            Select
          </Typography>
        );
      }

      return selected.join(", ");
    }}
   >
    <Box sx={{ height: "200px", overflow: "auto" }}>
      {displayedBlockOptions.map((option: any, i: any) => (
        <MenuItem key={i} value={option}>
          {option}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Box>
    <Box
      mt={2}
      display="flex"
      justifyContent="flex-end"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Button sx={{ mx: 1 }} size="small" variant="outlined">
        Cancel
      </Button>
      <Button sx={{ mx: 1 }} size="small" variant="contained">
        Done
      </Button>
    </Box>
   </Select>
   </div>
   );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Box and Button inside the Select component, use it like this:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

import { Select, Typography, MenuItem, Box, SelectChangeEvent, Button } from "@mui/material";

const displayedBlockOptions = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];

export default function App() {
    const [val, setVal] = useState<string[]>([]);

    const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof val>) => {
        const {
            target: { value },
        } = event;
        setVal(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
    };
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Box>
                <Select
                    displayEmpty
                    multiple
                    // MenuProps={{
                    //   sx: { height: "300px" }
                    // }}
                    value={val}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    renderValue={(selected: any) => {
                        if (selected.length === 0) {
                            return (
                                <Typography noWrap fontWeight={400} fontSize="13px">
                                    Select
                                </Typography>
                            );
                        }

                        return selected.join(", ");
                    }}>
                    {displayedBlockOptions.map((option: any, i: any) => (
                        <MenuItem key={i} value={option}>
                            {option}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            </Box>
            <Box mt={2} display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end" alignItems="center">
                <Button sx={{ mx: 1 }} size="small" variant="outlined">
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button sx={{ mx: 1 }} size="small" variant="contained">
                    Done
                </Button>
            </Box>
        </div>
    );
}
```